# Catel with Ninject

Tags: c#, mvvm, ninject, inversion-of-control, catel

Our company is using Ninject for DI. I have to create a WPF App with MVVM and want to use Catel.
Because our services which have the DB DataContext are injected with Ninject, I don't know where to start.

I've started with a prepared skeleton project.
This is what App.xaml.cs contains:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public IKernel Container;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ConfigureContainer();
        ComposeObjects();
        Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var modules = new INinjectModule[]
            {
                new ServiceModule()
            };

        Container = new StandardKernel(modules);
    }

    private void ComposeObjects()
    {
        Current.MainWindow = Container.Get<MainWindow>();
        Current.MainWindow.Title = "DI with Ninject";
    }
}
```

The `ServiceModule` is inherited from `NinjectModule`.

With that code I can use this constructor of my `MainWindow`:

```
public MainWindow(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(authenticationService);
    DataContext = ViewModel;
}
```

The `IAuthenticationService` is injected via App.xaml.cs and Ninject. In my opinion this solution is hard to maintain, because if I need a new service, I have to add it to the constructor of my `MainWindow`.
Now I need the same thing to work with Catel, but I haven't found something in the documentation.

**EDIT:
I've found on the documentation that I can register an external IoC container.
How do I create my own component (doc: Replacing the default components) which works with the Ninject's standard kernel?**

Also is this a good approach of DI or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the recommended approach on how to replace the default IoC components:

https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Replacing+the+default+components

To create your own component, let the Ninject kernel implement the right interface (for example, IDependencyResolver or IServiceLocator) and all should be set.

Comment: Do you mean this approach (NinjectDependencyResolver)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221314/catel-ninject-ninject-activationexception-when-resolving-iuivisualizerservice
If not, how do I let the Ninject kernel implement the interfaces?

Comment: No, the upcoming 4.0 has improved support for external containers. You can register the container (say Ninject ServiceLocator) and all services should automatically be registered for you.